# LIKE operator in active record query with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Product` model and an `Order` model. Suppose an order has a single product.

I want to search for all orders with product names that have the word "fruity"

The following query allows me to retrieve all orders whose associated product's name equal "fruity"

```
Order.joins(:product).where(:products => {:name => "fruity"})
```

But what I want to do is to use the `LIKE` operator. How can I do this using the query interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) lay this out pretty clearly.

You need a parameterized string argument to `where`:

```
Order.joins(:product).where('products.name like ?', '%fruity%')
```

You cannot do anything more complex then equality and `and`-based grouping by passing hashes to ActiveRecord; if you want negation, or `LIKE`, or `or`, you need to write a parameterized fragment of SQL:

```
...where('name = ? or name = ?', 'joe', 'bob') # only way to get 'or'
...where('name != ?', 'john') # only way to get 'not equal'
```

As of Rails 4, they've addressed negation via [`where.not`](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/not-equal-support-for-active-record-queries-rails-4-countdown-to-2013).

Comment: You can do negation in Rails 4 with the `Model.where.not` syntax.

Comment: Interesting, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

The `squeel` gem https://github.com/ernie/squeel#compound-conditions let's you do this without writing raw SQL.